# Spark Scala map fails with custom function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run a custom function in parallel on some parameters stored in RDD in spark scala. I assume using map should produce the result. I am getting an error when passing a custom function that I defined. There is no error if I pass some standard function instead(i.e. 'length' for instance). However, it does not look like a problem with specifically my function, because even if I pass empty custom function, it still fails. I would appreciate any suggestion.

To be specific, df_short is a dataframe with 6 columns and 1 row.:

```
df_short.show

|  1|  2|  3|   4|  5|   6|

| 10|0.5|0.4|0.05|0.7|0.07|
```

making this into RDD and then passing into map with standard function works:

```
df_short.rdd.map(i => i.length).collect
```

Next getting a custom function - a function that only returns 0

```
def grid_search_2(prm1: Int, prm2: Double, prm3: Double, prm4: Double, 
prm5: Double, prm6: Double): Int = {
return 0
}
```

Now trying to pass the custom function produces an error:

```
df_short.rdd.map(i => grid_search_2(i.getInt(0), i.getDouble(1), 
i.getDouble(2), i.getDouble(3), i.getDouble(4), i.getDouble(5))).collect
```

I get the following error:

```
va.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
.
.
.
.
```

The error is very lengthy and i can paste more of it. I would appreciate any help with finding out why this error happens - so far i did not have much luck with finding a solution. I am running spark version 2.4.3, scala version 2.11.12 and writing code in Zeppelin notebook.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because you use an instance method in your remote code (and not when you use `.map(i => i.length)`, which is an anonymous function).

I'm just guessing: As you utilize your instance method (which belongs to the "class" which is not directly visible from Zeppelin-Notebook) Spark tries to serialize the entire class. You could try to define a function object instead:

```
val grid_search_2 = (prm1: Int, prm2: Double, prm3: Double, prm4: Double, prm5: Double, prm6: Double) =>  {0}
```

And see if that makes any difference

Comment: I afraid your code is not working. I.e. the assignment that you have suggested is fine, but I am getting the same error when calling map. Thank you for suggesting, though!